# Showing user specific saved posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I'm somewhat of a  beginner in Django.
I am working with DRF and trying to create a saved posts page while implementing a filter to ensure that a suer only sees the posts he saved, but I tried the normal filter way and it's returning an empty list even though it is showing that there are saved posts in the saved posts table in the admin dashboard
here is the code for reference:

```
class SavedPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_saved')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='saved_user')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'profile')
```

this is the serializer:

```
class SavedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SavedPost
        fields = ('id','post', 'profile', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

and this is the Views:

```
  class SavedPostListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      queryset = SavedPost.objects.all()
      serializer_class = SavedPostSerializer
      authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
      permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
      ordering_fields=['created_at']
      def get_queryset(self):
          # Filter queryset to include only saved posts of the authenticated user
          return SavedPost.objects.filter(profile=self.request.user.profile)
```

I looked everywhere before asking here but didn't really find a solution I even went to chatGPT as a last resort and still the same answer

Comment: Please share your `SavedPost` model.

Comment: I did it and sorry for the confusion

Comment: So you are sure that there is data in the database for that profile? Note that the profile primary key and the user primary key might be different.

Comment: Can you share some (sample) data in the `SavedPost` model and `Profile` model, and print `print(self.request.user.pk)` in the `get_queryset` before returning the filtered queryset?

Comment: It was working with the author id and this is the updated Code


```
def get_queryset(self):
    # Filter queryset to include only saved posts of the authenticated user
    profile = self.request.data.get('profile')
    if profile is not None:
        return SavedPost.objects.filter(profile__id=profile)
    else:
        return SavedPost.objects.none()
```


this is the filtering code that should be put instead

Comment: but won't that return data for any profile you want? Like if you pass in the request the profile id of *another* user than yourself?

Comment: valid point it actually did 
I think it's a design flaw for the model to start with but here we are
It's a college project so it wouldn't really be an issue but in general it really is not the best way

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem take a look at his model, there is no `user` field in the `SavePost` model, by adding a `user` field, he can show current user post through: `SavePost.objects.filter(user=request.user)`,  retrieving `user` field to show an object of a model just because they have a relationship, it seems a bad practice to me.

Comment: @AdamuDeeAzare: yes, it is filtered on `Profile` and `Profile` is (likely) linked somehow to `User`, but likely some mapping is wrong here.

Comment: I don't know how your models are mapped but I would advise you to create a **Profile** model and then map it to **User** so that when you call User you have all the data. And then have **User** as **fk** in other models and then use  `request.user` to filter `profile=self.request.user.profile` is a bit too much